# jQuery Regex not triggering if statement

Tags: jquery, regex

** EDIT **
The regex was not accepting lowercase. Adding i did the trick.
Additionally I had to escape the \ out again in order for the past part of the regex to work.

Working one for jquery is following:

```
var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$', 'i');
```

I want to verify an email with a regex.

In my current code I see that it is executing the function but not going into the if statement even though the regex matches.

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
    var INPUT = $(this).val();
    var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');
    if (email.test(INPUT)) {
        console.log('inside the if');
    }
    console.log('Outside the if');
});
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Isn't the backslash escaping the `.`?

Comment: Don't you want this to be case insensitive? `new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$', 'i')`

Comment: It sounds unlikely that the regex matches if it doesn't enter the if clause. As mentioned, it seems unlikely that the email addresses you test only contain upper case letters.

Comment: From what I can see, your regex allows only uppercase. You need `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, which is equivalent if I am correct to `\w`. [Mohamed-Yousef's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30643129/1734119) seems quite close to something conclusive. Looking for [pre-existing solutions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) were a nice move. Maybe if you add the case-insensitive flag, you would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex seems fine, just need to set the case insensitive flag:

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
    var INPUT = $(this).val();
    var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$', 'i');
    if (email.test(INPUT)) {
        console.log('inside the if');
    }
    console.log('Outside the if');
});
```

Comment: Let it be known that I dislike the naming of the variable `INPUT`. Especially when `email` is lowercase :)